# I am finding google weave projects sample

Tags: google-weave

I want to find google weave projects samples. but I can't find it.

please give me some urls about iot project using google weave.

thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Weave is maintained at [weave.googlesource.com](https://weave.googlesource.com/). Here are links to the [examples](https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/master/examples/) and [docs](https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/master/docs/) contained within that repository.

These are also all linked from the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/weave/guides/device-dev/getting-started) guide in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for samples working on hardware, checkout the [light sample](https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/libiota-v2.0.0/examples/mw302/light/main.c) and [codelab](https://weave.googlesource.com/weave/libiota/+/libiota-v2.0.0/platform/mw302/CODELAB.md) for mw302.

These would save you a lot of time tracing sample codes.